# Make edits to JSON object that was iterated through?

Tags: reactjs, json, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Having another brain fart of an issue in React. I looped through arrays & made objects iterable in React AND THEN built forms (text fields) for each entry. NOW I want to be able to make saved changes in these forms and send out the ENTIRE JSON Object to the server. Is there an easy way to accomplish this or will I have to retrace my steps & build a TON of logic around going back the tree or changing the data types in the json??

```
 {el.sect.map(elo=>{
                   
                      return(
                      <React.Fragment key={elo.item+1}>
                          <Col key={elo.item+2} md={5} xs={10} id="Imenu">{elo.item}</Col>
                          <Col key={elo.item+3} md={1} xs={2} id="Mprice"><Form.Control value={elo.price} type="text"/></Col>
                      </React.Fragment>
                    );
                    
                  })}
```

Here is an example of the JSON. The elo is iterated from the main object array so its harder to just find the 'key' to tap into

```
{
"head":"Specialty Milkshakes",
"sect":[
    {
        "item":"Chocolate Peanut Butter",
        "price":"$5.49"
    },
    {
        "item":"Mint Chocolate Chip",
        "price":"$5.49"
    }
]
```

},

Comment: Does the `name` or `id` available in `elo`  object?  Your id `Imenu` and `Mprice` is repeated, ids should unique.'

Comment: It should be yes, I just modified it to show a sample of the JSON data. so I can get the keys of "name" and "price" to alter it but its part of an array which complicates things. like I'd probably have to rebuild the array every time its written out to screen, dont I?